# How to use knockout.js with leaflet.js map markers?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js, leaflet

We are building a web visualization for industial plants that are located on different locations. At the moment, we use a table layout for our overview page. Each row represents one plant and its most important states and values.

Now there's the requirement to alternatively show a map with markers. Each markers' color should represent the current state (green=ok, red=error, yellow=warning etc).

In our current table-based page we use knockout.js to bind the individual plants properties from the viewmodel to the table rows (and the corresponding div's etc. within it). The viewmodel's values get updated via signalr whenever a state or value changes, so you can consider this as a realtime, event-based representation of the plants states.

As this viewmodel already contains all the information we need to show on the map, I'd like to bind the leaflet markers to the viewmodel, but I can't see a way how to do that. The problem is that there is no element for a markes that I can use with the `data-bind` attribute.

To be precise: I can add (static) markers for each plant, that's not the thing, but I can't data-bind them to the viewmodel in order to dynamically represent the changing values in the viewmodel. Is there a way to do it?

I'd really like to go on with leaflet as it perfectly fits our needs. The web application needs to run in a special net that is permanently disconnected to the internet, so we need to serve our own tiles (which works great with leaflet and Maperetive). If there is another solution other than leaflet that could fit our needs, please let me know, too. Thanks!

Update: Here's the actual json data of my viewmodel. Each row represents a station. The latitude / longitude for each station has not been added yet, but that's negligible for this issue, I guess.

```
{
   "Rows":[
      {
         "StationId":1,
         "Text":"MCU SE (SE 1/1) DAE",
         "IsDialInStation":false,
         "ConnectState":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":14,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1400149092000)\/"
         },
         "ConnectStateText":"Nicht verbunden. Hier klicken für Anwahl!",
         "HasActualData":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":10,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1404890137000)\/"
         },
         "Anlage":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20101,
            "Name":"Anlage",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteAnlage":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20013,
            "Name":"cmdAnlage",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Kurzzeit":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20104,
            "Name":"Kurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteKurzzeit":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20012,
            "Name":"cmdKurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Handbetrieb":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20160,
            "Name":"Handbetrieb",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Betriebsbereit":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20121,
            "Name":"Betriebsbereit",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Heizt":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20451,
            "Name":"Heizt",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Sammelstoerung":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20140,
            "Name":"Sammelstoerung",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "SammelstoerungTechnisch":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20129,
            "Name":"SammelstoerungTechnisch",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerung":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20138,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerung",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerungKE":{
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20137,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerungKE",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "AllowCommands":true,
         "AllowParameters":true
      },
      {
         "StationId":2,
         "Text":"MCU SE (SE 2/1) Turm",
         "IsDialInStation":false,
         "ConnectState":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":14,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1402984603000)\/"
         },
         "ConnectStateText":"Nicht verbunden. Hier klicken für Anwahl!",
         "HasActualData":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":10,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1404890136000)\/"
         },
         "Anlage":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20101,
            "Name":"Anlage",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteAnlage":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20013,
            "Name":"cmdAnlage",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Kurzzeit":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20104,
            "Name":"Kurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteKurzzeit":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20012,
            "Name":"cmdKurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Handbetrieb":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20160,
            "Name":"Handbetrieb",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Betriebsbereit":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20121,
            "Name":"Betriebsbereit",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Heizt":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20451,
            "Name":"Heizt",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Sammelstoerung":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20140,
            "Name":"Sammelstoerung",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "SammelstoerungTechnisch":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20129,
            "Name":"SammelstoerungTechnisch",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerung":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20138,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerung",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerungKE":{
            "StationId":2,
            "DpId":20137,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerungKE",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "AllowCommands":true,
         "AllowParameters":true
      },
      {
         "StationId":4,
         "Text":"Test W 1",
         "IsDialInStation":false,
         "ConnectState":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":14,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1402996083000)\/"
         },
         "ConnectStateText":"Nicht verbunden. Hier klicken für Anwahl!",
         "HasActualData":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":10,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1404890134000)\/"
         },
         "Anlage":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20101,
            "Name":"Anlage",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteAnlage":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20013,
            "Name":"cmdAnlage",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Kurzzeit":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20104,
            "Name":"Kurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteKurzzeit":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20012,
            "Name":"cmdKurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Handbetrieb":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20160,
            "Name":"Handbetrieb",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Betriebsbereit":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20121,
            "Name":"Betriebsbereit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Heizt":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20451,
            "Name":"Heizt",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Sammelstoerung":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20140,
            "Name":"Sammelstoerung",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "SammelstoerungTechnisch":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20129,
            "Name":"SammelstoerungTechnisch",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerung":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20138,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerung",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerungKE":{
            "StationId":4,
            "DpId":20137,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerungKE",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "AllowCommands":true,
         "AllowParameters":true
      },
      {
         "StationId":3,
         "Text":"Test W 2",
         "IsDialInStation":false,
         "ConnectState":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":14,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1402996031000)\/"
         },
         "ConnectStateText":"Nicht verbunden. Hier klicken für Anwahl!",
         "HasActualData":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":10,
            "Name":null,
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1405488343000)\/"
         },
         "Anlage":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20101,
            "Name":"Anlage",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteAnlage":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20013,
            "Name":"cmdAnlage",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Kurzzeit":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20104,
            "Name":"Kurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "cmdSchalteKurzzeit":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20012,
            "Name":"cmdKurzzeit",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Handbetrieb":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20160,
            "Name":"Handbetrieb",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Betriebsbereit":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20121,
            "Name":"Betriebsbereit",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Heizt":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20451,
            "Name":"Heizt",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "Sammelstoerung":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20140,
            "Name":"Sammelstoerung",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "SammelstoerungTechnisch":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20129,
            "Name":"SammelstoerungTechnisch",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerung":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20138,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerung",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "KommunikationsStoerungKE":{
            "StationId":3,
            "DpId":20137,
            "Name":"KommunikationsStoerungKE",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
         },
         "AllowCommands":true,
         "AllowParameters":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What values exist for a marker? Is it only state that changes and you want the color to change?

Comment: Since it seems you can't really work with the markup, you will need to insert/update markers with js. You can still use the `subscribe` function to get the updates of the viewmodel and pass them on the markers.

Comment: That would be a good start, but in the end there's more: a text that shows a value and one that show the plants name.

Comment: You could look into writing a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) which will plot your markers.

Comment: can You please provide some json for each marker. That would help a great deal in answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with OpenLayers, so this answer might not be the greatest, but it might give you some insight into how you can take a view-model of markers and 'bind' it to a map such that any change to the view-model is reflected on the map. The key for me was to write a subscriber function that renders the waypoints.

Here's my basic view-model. I call them waypoints, but they are OpenLayers.Geometry.Point objects, so I am willing to guess they are similar to the Leaflet markers.

```
G.WaypointsViewModel = function() {
    // The list of waypoints.
    this.waypoints = ko.observableArray([])
}
```

I build a subscriber like this; the comment is from my actual code, so I guess we're both suffering from the same problem!

```
// We cannot bind the OpenLayers line that links these waypoints to the
// waypoint list, so we need a manual subscription to update the line.
this.waypoints.subscribe(function(new_waypoints) {

}
```

Ideally I'd write some clever code that worked out what had changed in the view model, and just do the correct updates, but for simplicity the first thing my function does is get rid of all the current waypoints:

```
this.waypoints.subscribe(function(new_waypoints) {
    // Don't continue with an empty array.
    if (new_waypoints.length == 0) return

    // Get rid of the current drawings.
    this.removeMarkers() 
    ...
```

In OpenLayers, removing markers is easy; I just call destroyFeatures on my variable representing the marker layer:

```
    this.marker_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Markers Layer", {
        style: G.default_line_style
    })

    this.removeMarkers = function() {
        marker_layer.destroyFeatures()
    }
```

Then I redraw all the markers:

```
    while (waypoint = this.waypoints()[i]) {
        marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            waypoint, {type: 'waypoint', index: i}
        )
        this.marker_layer.addFeatures(marker)

        // Next...
        i++
    }
```

Now this is all set up, anything the user does in the app that causes a change to the waypoints (eg deleting waypoints, moving them, etc) means the map is automatically updated by the KO subscriber.

The full code for this view-model (which has a fair few other things going on) is here:

http://simonlikesmaps.appspot.com/js/app/view_models/G.WaypointsViewModel.js

The app that uses it is here:

http://simonlikesmaps.appspot.com/

Hopefully that gives you some inspiration for doing the same with Leaflet.

---

In fact, I've been meaning to read about Leaflet for a while, so I went and read, and sketched up the above pattern into a ViewModel that should work with Leaflet. Warning - this is untested - so is bound to have some errors!

```
MarkersVM = function() {

    // Create leaflet map
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    // Add a marker layer
    this.addMarkerLayer();

    // Turn your JSON into an array of station, each with a lat/lon
    this.markers = ko.observableArray([
        {
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20101,
            "Name":"Anlage",
            "Value":1,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
            "lat": "51",
            "lon": "0"
         },
         {
            "StationId":1,
            "DpId":20013,
            "Name":"cmdAnlage",
            "Value":0,
            "TimeStamp":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
            "lat": "52",
            "lon": "1"
         },
    ]);

    // Subscribe to the array, to redraw the map.
    this.markers.subscribe(function(new_markers) {
        // Don't bother with an empty array
        if (new_markers.length == 0) return;

        // Start be removing all current markers; to do this, remove the marker layer.
        map.removeLayer(this.markers);

        // Add a fresh marker layer.
        this.addMarkerLayer();

        // Now add the points.
        var i = 0, marker;
        while (station = this.markers()[i]) {
            var marker = L.marker(station.lat, station.lon)

            // You can manipulate the marker here, eg add the name, the text, etc

            this.markers.add(marker);
        }
    }, this);

    this.addMarkerLayer = function() {
        this.markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
        map.addLayer(this.markers);
    }
}
```

With this, any change made to the JSON will change the markers array in the view-model which via the subscribed function will destroy the markers on the map then draw new ones, ensuring the new information is automatically shown in the map.